# Computing surface integral for $F(x,y,z) = (xy,-x^2,x+z)$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, surface-integrals

> Let $F: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3, F(x,y,z) = (xy,-x^2,x+z)$ be a vector field. Compute the surface integral over the set $S$ which is bounded by the plane $2x+2y+z=6$ in the set $\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x,y,z\geqslant 0 \}.$

So I would need to calculate $$\iint_{T}f(\varphi(x,y)) \|\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x} \times \frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial y} \|  \ dx \ dy$$

Parameterizing $F$ as $\varphi(x,y) = (x,y, 6-2x-2y)$ I have that $$\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x}=(1,0,-2) \text{ and } \frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial y}=(0,1,-2)$$

so $\|\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x} \times \frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial y} \| = \| (2,2,1)\| = 3.$

Computing the composition $f\circ\varphi$ I get that $f(x,y,6-2x-2y)=(x^2y,-y^2,x+6-2x-2y)$, thus the integral I would need to compute is $$\iint_{T} (x^2y,-y^2,x+6-2x-2y)\cdot 3 \ dx \ dy$$

but this seems wrong, this is just $f(\varphi(x,y)$ scaled by $3$. What am I missing here? Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: If $F$ had been a scalar function, i.e. $F:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R$, then your attempt would have been correct. But $\vec F$ is vector-valued, $\vec F:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$, so the surface element would be$$\mathrm d\vec S=\vec n\,\mathrm dS=\frac{\varphi_x\times\varphi_y}{\|\varphi_x\times\varphi_y\|}\|\varphi_x\times\varphi_y\|\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy=(\varphi_x\times\varphi_y)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$$You also have to take orientation into account, which would affect the order of the partial derivatives in $\varphi_x\times\varphi_y$ and hence the sign of the integral.

Comment: You are taking curl of the the vector field. The question does not state that. Even if that was the case, the mistake that you are making is to take magnitude of the normal vector $\|\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x} \times \frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial y} \|$. You should instead do a dot product of the vector field with normal vector $(2,2,1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should evaluate the **flux** of the vector field $\vec{F}$ through the given surface $S$, a triangle where the normal vector $\vec{n}$ is constant:
$$\begin{align}\iint_S \vec{F} \cdot \vec{n} \ dS&=\iint_{T}\vec{F}(\varphi(x,y)) \cdot \left(\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x} \times \frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial y}\right) \ dx dy
\\&=\iint_T (xy,-x^2,x+(6-2x-2y))\cdot(2,2,1)\, dx\,dy
\end{align}$$
where $\varphi(x,y)=(x,y, 6-2x-2y)$ and $T=\{(x,y): x+y\leq 3,x\ge 0,y\ge 0\}$.

As a reference, see [wikipage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral#Surface_integrals_of_vector_fields).

Comment: Ah, indeed the flux. I'm confused with all the different definitions... The bounds for the integrals are still confusing me a little bit. Are you seperating the bounds with the comma for the different integrals?

Comment: No, the domain is the triangle $T=\{(x,y): x+y\leq 3,x\ge 0,y\ge 0\}$ in the $xy$-plane (let $z=0$ in the given plane) . Have you a numeric answer to check?

Comment: You should not be dividing $(2,2,1)$ by $3$. $dS = 3 \, dx \, dy$ so it cancels out.

Comment: @MathLover Yes, you are correct. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Is there a typo in the composition $F(\varphi(x,y))$ or did I just compute it the wrong way? @RobertZ

Comment: We are evaluating the vector $\vec{F}(x,y,z)$ with $(x,y)\in T$  and $z$ such that $2+2+=6$. That is $\vec{F}(\varphi(x,y))$, with $\varphi(x,y)=(x,y, 6-2x-2y)$.